# Remote usage to better unit

Tags: remote-control

I have a great HP Z2 G5 work station connected to 4k 55" tv that I use.

*Scenario- But sometimes I remote in using TS/RDP (remote desktop) from my old reliable Dell E6410 with Win 10 Pro (back from 2010). And sometimes connect another monitor or use my docking station setup with multiple monitors. When I do that, which machines hardware is being used, and for what purposes e.g. CPU, RAM, graphics, etc. The Z2 has Nvidia T1000.

Or if I use Teamviewer or Gotomypc, I always wonder what machines resources are being used for what.
Is it possible someone can point me to where I need to go to research and find out this info? Frustrating that I can't seem to find it all in 1 source.

I know a lot of stuff being in IT over 2 decades, excellent level 1/2/3 tech in many regards and technologies and applications. BUT NOT THAT, just not something I've studied. Used plenty, but not by total understanding it.
Advice and knowledge sharing is very welcome, and thank you.

[image]